# One console app, many configuration files

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a .NET console app (with 10 referenced custom dll:s) that will be reused multiple times with different configuration files (app.config and custom .config-files).

The trivial solution is to just copy and paste all the exe and dll:s to different directories and change the .config-files for every directory.

But that makes it difficult when updating code.

How can I accomplish this without duplicating (binary)code?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the programm from a other dir where you second or third config file is located.

Windows looks normally first in the exe files directory so your referenced assamblys should be no problem.

Comment: The referenced dll:s are not framework dll:s, it my own dll:s. They all need to be in the same directory.

Comment: Did you try to call your exe file from another directory? I'm pretty sure that this will work. Just now I'm not sure if your app will read the correct config file under some conditions.

Comment: The .exe will read the .exe.config that resides in the same directory as the .exe. I can't se how a different "calling-directory" will make any difference. Please share with an example how to accomplish this.

Comment: This are that conditions I was talking about. Try to remove the config file from the exe dir. For the other I need to write a test app. This could take some time sorry!